# Notification not coming via Firebase console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]
[image]

I have tried every possible solutions for above issue but still not getting notification to my device via Firebase Console. Please suggest.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
FIRApp.configure()
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {

        self.handleNotification(remoteNotification as! [NSObject : AnyObject])
    }
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    NSNotificationCenter
        .defaultCenter()
        .addObserver(self, selector: #selector(AppDelegate.tokenRefreshNotificaiton),
                     name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)
return true }
 func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)



    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTheTable", object: nil)


}

 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
}
func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        else {
            return
    }


    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    utill.tokenDefault.setValue(refreshedToken, forKey: "tokenId")

    connectToFcm()
}
```

Few firebase warnings are also displaying in the debugger:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Issue Resolved for me.
I skipped uploading APNs development certificate.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have enabled push notification capabilities from project target capabilities section shown in the picture if you are deploying the application from Xcode 8 or later.
[image]

Comment: push notification is enabled.

Comment: The Log in above screenshot shows Failed to get APNS Token.please check that you received  device token and have uploaded right p12 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the ios version. ios 10 requires UNUserNotificationCenter. Try the code below and add the function to your application didFinishLaunching.

```
    func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if you have done this but you need to go to firebase project settings, choose cloud messaging and upload APNs development certificate for development stage in order to receive firebase notification. You also need a real device in order to receive notification. Unable to do notification testing on simulators.