# FCM notification issue - swift3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, unusernotificationcenter

I have successfully added firebase and notification in my project. [Using this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132530/notification-not-coming-via-firebase-console) Notifications are coming and I can access them by tapping on that notification. But the issue is if my app is closed, I got a notification, now without tapping on that I cleared that. Now no data inserted in my Db. How to keep all notifications on queue to access directly when app is opened next time. Thanks in advance.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate , CLLocationManagerDelegate , FIRMessagingDelegate , UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var utill = FencingUtil()
var wrap = WrapperApi()
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if launchOptions != nil{
        let userInfo = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]
        if userInfo != nil {
            self.handleUserInfo(userinfo: userInfo as! [AnyHashable : Any])
            // Perform action here
        }
    }
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 50.0; // Will notify the LocationManager every 100 meters
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyDNoFY_sbP9j-ObZx06B_rmjcCVrCM_ZP0")
    GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyDNoFY_sbP9j-ObZx06B_rmjcCVrCM_ZP0")

    FIRApp.configure()
   // var db: SQLiteDatabase
    let dataStore = SQLiteDataStore.sharedInstance
            do {
                try dataStore.createTables()
            }
            catch _{}
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .sound, .alert], completionHandler: {(grant, error)  in
            if error == nil {
                if grant {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                } else {
                    //User didn't grant permission
                }
            } else {
                print("error: ",error)
            }
        })
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
        UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from foreground")
    // custom code to handle push while app is in the foreground
    //print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
    self.handleUserInfo(userinfo: notification.request.content.userInfo)
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Handle push from background or closed")
    // if you set a member variable in didReceiveRemoteNotification, you will know if this is from closed or background

    self.handleUserInfo(userinfo: response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
}

func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)
{
    print("%@", remoteMessage.appData)
}
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any])
{ self.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo) { (UIBackgroundFetchResult) in }
    print ("dasdasd")

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
 self.handleUserInfo(userinfo: userInfo)

}
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)



}
func tokenRefreshNotificaiton(_ notification: Foundation.Notification) {
    guard let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        else {
            return
    }
    //refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!

    print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

    utill.tokenDefault.setValue(refreshedToken, forKey: "tokenId")
    // Connect to FCM since connection may have failed when attempted before having a token.
    connectToFcm()
}
// [START connect_to_fcm]
func connectToFcm() {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().connect { (error) in
        if (error != nil) {
            print("Unable to connect with FCM. \(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            //print("Connected to FCM.")
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: you are saying that you have cleared notification from notification center and after removing you want to save it on DB?

Comment: Yes, Is it possible to directly access the notification when app is in background mode?

Comment: if you are removing notification from notification center you can not get the object of notification.check my answer to get object in  didfinish launch.

Answer (score 1):

if you are launching your application then you can get you notification object in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method try this. if you have 
not cleared notification from notification center.

```
        if (launchOptions != nil) {
        if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?
       [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification]  {
          let objNotification = remoteNotification as! [AnyHashable : 
         Any]
          }
    }
```

Comment: Launghing App not calling this function.